# Can't display to console received JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

I'm trying to receive large array with JSON objects from remote server. Server-side based on Node.js + redis. My ajax query:

```
$.ajax({
    crossDomain: true,
    type:"GET",
    contentType: "application/json",
    url: "http://****.amazonaws.com:8080/?userlist=1",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    jsonp: false,
    cache: true,
    jsonpCallback: function(data){console.log(data)}
});
```

On Network->Response tab I see array, what I want to receive. Example:

```
[
    {
        "uid": 1,
        "username": "jf",
        "firstname": "Annunn",
        "lastname": "Uv",
        "photolink": "https://newsz.s3.amazonaws.com/users/male.jpg",
        "bubblecolor": 7,
        "chattscore": 125,
        "city": "Regina",
        "country": "CA",
        "locale": "CA",
        "refreshtime": 5
    },
    {
        "uid": 2,
        "username": "ypfoub",
        "firstname": "Gljissash",
        "lastname": "Braud",
        "photolink": "https://newsz.s3.amazonaws.com/users/female.jpg",
        "bubblecolor": 2,
        "chattscore": 125,
        "city": "Salt Lake City",
        "country": "US",
        "locale": "US",
        "refreshtime": 5
    }
]
```

But I can't do something with this response. jsonpCallback function returns undefined.
Thanks

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Half your arguments to the ajax call make no sense in any circumstance, and half of what are left make no sense in this circumstance.

```
crossDomain: true,
```

You should only use this if you are making a request to the same origin that gets redirected to a different origin. Don't do that.

```
type:"GET",
```

This is fine.

```
contentType: "application/json",
```

You are making a GET request. There is no content in the request. Don't specify a content type.

```
url: "http://****.amazonaws.com:8080/?userlist=1",
```

This is fine for a normal request, but if you were to use JSONP then you should add `&callback=?` to it.

```
dataType: "jsonp",
```

The response you are getting is not JSONP. Why are you telling jQuery to expect JSONP?

```
jsonp: false,
```

Remove this unless you are making a JSONP request using a non-standard callback name query string parameter. If you *are* doing that, then this should be a string, not a boolean.

```
cache: true,
```

This is fine.

```
jsonpCallback: function(data){console.log(data)}
```

If you are using JSONP, then let jQuery generate a name. There is almost never any reason to do it manually.

If you really want to override the name generation, then you must specify either a string or a function that returns a string. This is neither.

You have not specified anywhere what you want to do with the response. Presumably you are confusing `jsonpCallback` with `success`.

---

What you need to do:

Decide if you are using JSON or JSONP.

If you are using JSONP, then change the server side script you are making the request to so it returns a JSONP response.

Then use:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "http://****.amazonaws.com:8080/?userlist=1&callback=?",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data){console.log(data)}
});
```

If you are not using JSONP, then (if you haven't already) change the server side script so it includes CORS headers.

Then use:

```
$.ajax({
    type:"GET",
    url: "http://****.amazonaws.com:8080/?userlist=1",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){console.log(data)}
});
```

Comment: success callback didn't display anything to console, so it's not working

Comment: Which of the two approaches I suggested did you take? What does the Net tab show now? What does the JavaScript error console say?

Comment: I took first one with dataType: "jsonp". Net tab shows the same response. Console still says only 

`Object {readyState: 1, getResponseHeader: function, getAllResponseHeaders: function, setRequestHeader: function, overrideMimeType: function…}`

Comment: If the Net tab shows the same response then you didn't do what I said, which was: change the server side script you are making the request to so it returns a JSONP response

Comment: I have changed this string on server side:
`response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "application/jsonp"});`
maybe i should do something else?

Comment: Yes. It does no good to make up a MIME type and claim that JSON is really something else.  The correct MIME type for JSONP is `application/javascript` and the body has to be formatted as JSONP (which means a JavaScript function call (to the function name specified in the `callback` query string argument) with the data passed as the first argument.